# Running imported projects on netbeans fails to build

Tags: netbeans, build, import, project

When I export my project to a zip, and then try to import it on another computer I always get this error:

```
Created dir: C:\Users\martins0011\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Movicol\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\martins0011\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Movicol\build\web\META-INF
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\martins0011\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Movicol\build\web\META-INF
Copying 63 files to C:\Users\martins0011\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Movicol\build\web
C:\Users\martins0011\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Movicol\nbproject\build-impl.xml:846: C:\Users\martins0011\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Movicol\web\WEB-INF does not exist.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

What causes this error?

Comment: Show us the build-impl around line 846.  And does your `C:\Users\martins0011\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Movicol\web\WEB-INF` exist?  Are you trying to create it?  Apparently you are issuing a command that requires the file to exist, but it does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed it creating the folder WEB-INF manually on the directory of the project... weird bug, but solved, I can run it now! thanks alot anyway Eric!

Comment: Got a similiar error, that build/web/WEB-INF did not existed, created the folder inside /web and it worked like a charm

Comment: I cloned a git repo and had this same problem. This fixed it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while building a web project(JSP) on netbeans 7.2, then I created the WEB_INF manually and the project was successfully rebuilt. Note that this missing file comes from GIT hub upon fetching the web project, at least in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in this year (2020) and **I solved by copying and adding the webinf file into the web file in my project**. And it doesn't matter where you take this file(webinf) it'll work from every project you choose to copy it.